# F# Cannot find DLL

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am currently learning F# and working through the samples on tryfsharp.org. I am using the Mono F# on a Mac.The script begins as follows:

```
#r "MathNet.Numerics.dll"
open MathNet.Numerics
open System.Numerics
```

When starting the script I get the following error message:
    /Users/benjamin/Desktop/Kalman/kalman.fsx(1,1): error FS0078: Unable to find the file '
    MathNet.Numerics.dll' in any of
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.12/lib/mono/4.5
    /Users/benjamin/Desktop/Kalman
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.12/lib/m

I do not know, where to find that DLL or how to install it.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use nuget to get that library.

http://nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics

See here to install nuget:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq

Comment: Yeah.  Then what?  These still aren't in the search path.  Should we have to provide the full path?

Comment: @uosɐſ you can use `#I` to include a path to search.  FSI is independent of the solution you're currently using.  See here for all the special scripting commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  It does seem to be sensitive to the project's directory.  Nothing less than `#r @"..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.3.0.0-alpha7\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.dll"` seems to work.

Comment: @uosɐſ the `#I` to the path followed by `#r` on the assembly didn't work?

Comment: Wow, it's like I didn't even read your first sentence to me!  Sorry.  You're right that setting the include path would work.